# In standard, interpret characters as vectors

Tags: math-mode, environments, matrices, vector

I need to write many equations with way more matrices and vectors than scalars and I would like to have LaTeX interpret "normal" characters as vectors and matrices. Consequently I need to mark the scalars. An example usage is demonstrated in my commented code example. I think of using a special environment but who knows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\ve#1{{\mathchoice{\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle #1$}}
              {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle #1$}}%
              {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle #1$}}%
              {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle #1$}}}}
\def\inv{^{-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
(\ve{A}+\ve{U}\ve{C}\ve{V})\inv+A+\ve{b}=\ve{A}\inv-\ve{A}^{-1}\ve{U}(\ve{C}\inv+\ve{V}\ve{A}\inv\ve{U})\inv\ve{V}\ve{A}\inv+A+\ve{b}
\end{equation*}
%\begin{equation*}
%(A+UCV)\inv=A\inv-A\inv U(C\inv+VA\inv U)\inv VA\inv+\scalar{A}+b
%\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\usepackage{bm}` and then `\newcommand{\ve}[1]{\bm{#1}}` be easier?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `\ve` is essentially a version of `\boldsymbol` in most cases `\bm` is more efficient.
However here I think you just want to declare a bold math italic alphabet:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbi}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\def\inv{^{-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}\mathbi{
(A+UCV)\inv+A+b=A\inv-A^{-1}U(C\inv+VA\inv U)\inv VA\inv+A+b +\mathnormal{abc} + \mathnormal{A}
}\end{equation*}
%\begin{equation*}
%(A+UCV)\inv=A\inv-A\inv U(C\inv+VA\inv U)\inv VA\inv+\scalar{A}+b
%\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't make the command "\ve". I got it from my university. What would be your alternative?

Comment: @apfel as I say you could use \bm (bm package) or \boldsymbol (amsmath package) or \mathbi (as defined in this answer) all three are more efficient (the last a lot more efficient) than `\ve` as defined in your question.

Comment: 2 questions: Is it possible to exclude numbers from becoming bold by default? Why is it not possible to use "\\" i.e. newline in "\mathbi" environment and how can this functionality be included?

Comment: Also numbers get tiny. "\mathnormal" does not give them normal size.

Comment: You could change the mathcode of digits so they don't get bold but then they would never change fonts with mathalphabet sweitches, just like symbols. `\\ ` works inside `\mathbf` as well as outside but it doesn't work in `equation` you need ams `align` for multi-line displays